# Different Terms&Conditions on multi-site

Tags: multi-sites, domain-access

I use [Legal](https://www.drupal.org/project/legal) module to display terms & conditions to the user, but now I need to create different T&C text for different sites created with Domain Access. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 [Domain Variable](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_variable) module will help you, in Drupal 6 this is not supported probably.

**Domain Variable:**

> This module aims to be a replacement variable handling module for [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain), allowing mixed variable realms (domain x language) to be configured.
>
> In other words, it allows setting different variable values for each domain and for each language at the same time.
>
> This module supports almost all of the functionality provided by Domain Configuration, Domain Settings and Domain Theme. Differences are listed in the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1856898).